# jakarta..servlet.ServletContainer Exception

Tags: hibernate, rest

I am trying to build a RESTful API Web app using Hibernate and MySql and when I try to run the program I came across this exception. It says :
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:

1. java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator not a subtype
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on project.restful.showroom.resources.Brand

This is my pom.xml

`

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>project.restful</groupId>
<artifactId>setUp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>setUp</name>

<build>
    <finalName>setUp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x
        compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>3.1.5</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <war.mvn.plugin.version>3.4.0</war.mvn.plugin.version>
</properties>
```

`

Where is the error coming from it is asking for hibernate files that do not exist. What should I do? I do not even know how to put the problem.

P.S. After adding all the hibernate maven dependencies, the new exception is jakarta.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:

1. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: EnversService#initialize should be called only once
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on project.restful.showroom.resources.Brand

   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:409)
   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:357)
   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:311)
   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)

I do not know how to proceed after this. Please help.